# How to automatically adjust the size of listboxitem?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have created a listbox which has a horizontal orientation. When I load the content, in the stackpanel the size of stackpanel will automatically adjust to the size of the content stored inside. How do I achieve this in a listbox?

This is my listboxcode in XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="WebScrollView" 
             Grid.Row="2" 
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
             SelectionMode="Multiple" 
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>           
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: what content you have load if image mention the dimensions?

Comment: I have a webbrowser inside, which is added to the listbox when it has successfully navigated. When I add it to a stackpanel, it resizes, but the listbox sets the height to default 0.0 when not specified. 
So that's the problem: I cannot hard-code it, because one webview might be 1000 in height, the next maybe 2000 or even 3000. 
So in other words: I do not specify the height

Comment: If I do set the height of the browser to, say, 1500, it displays it as normal.

Answer (score 1):

WebBrowser is a very expensive control for both CPU and memory. Creating a separate instance of a WebBrowser for each item in a ListBox seems like a bad idea for that reason alone. I suggest that you use the Html Agility Pack to extract the fields you want and bind them into TextBlocks and other controls. You'll also gain much greater control over the display of each item.

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/